"Highly skilled" or "high-skilled"?
I've seen multiple academic sources use these interchangeably — even one noting it's done consciously — but my inclination as a native speaker is (was?) that "highly skilled" is always correct and "high-skilled" isn't.
However, I noticed that there's a trend toward "high-skilled," even if it remains in the minority as of 2019.
Which is correct?  Or are they interchangeable?  Do any style guides address this specifically?

Could "high-skilled" be an Indian English thing? (The paper you cite is Indian.) NGrams still shows that "highly skilled" is far more common in UK and US but doesn't have a separate thing for Indian English. (But note "high" can be an adverb too so it's not ungrammatical.)

I (Australian) have never heard "high-skilled", and on reading it I automatically wondered how it would differ from "highly skilled". As a result it suggested to me somebody who has learned advanced skills, but may not be highly competent.

"high-flying" is common, so maybe it's modelled on that (you "fly high" not "fly highly").

Examples of ‘high-skilled’ people: steeplejacks, trapeze artists, airship pilots, astronauts…

Yeah, with those ngrams it would be good to actually see where they dredge "high skill" up from.

Consider... high-skilled vs. low-skilled — which works — and highly skilled vs. lowly skilled — which does not.

Word Reference includes both 'high skilled' and 'highly skilled' in its list of (...)

Forum discussions with the word(s) "skilled" in the title:

high-skilled workers
highly skilled workers

...

Collins Online Dictionary and Cambridge Dictionary  list 'highly skilled' but not 'high-skilled'. Merriam-Webster includes only an example of the former.
But Thesaurus.com includes examples containing both 'highly-skilled' and 'low-skilled':


Highly-skilled professionals across sectors have a leg up when employers cherry-pick roles to reward. [Quartz]

However, the enormous benefits that low-skilled immigrants provide more than make up for that relatively small cost. [Daily Beast]



(but of course, 'lowly skilled' would be farcical, with or without a hyphen).
A Wikipedia article contains skilled, unskilled, semi-skilled, non-skilled and highly-skilled, as well as "Obama Immigration Order to Impact Millions, Includes Provisions for High-Skilled Workers".
Although many credible examples for the collocation/compound adjective 'high skilled' can be found on the internet, Google ngram results would indicate a 5 : 1 ratio in favour of 'highly skilled' at the moment.
So the best policy is to choose the favoured form, and not be upset if someone chooses the valid alternative.

I've been trying to figure out how somebody can manage to skill high, but so far am complete stumped myself. :)

Probably the same way someone can belly yellow, face two, or heart half.

This usage chart clearly shows how quickly the "flat" format has taken off in just the last couple of decades. It certainly looks as if (hyphenated) high-skilled workers will overtake (unhyphenated) highly skilled workers within the next decade or so. I'm a bit baffled as to why the emerging form is so firmly wedded to the hyphen, but there it is.

High-skilled can be parsed the same way as red-haired or warm-hearted. All such scraps of the form ADJ-Ned have the meaning of “possessing or characterized by (a) N that is ADJ.”
The particular one you ask about, high-skilled, is on the same model as high-strung, high-handed, and high-spirited… and even the solid-set highborn. It may, however, be a good deal less idiomatic than all these others.

In my personal experience, 'high-skilled' is exclusively used by South Asian people (i.e. from Pakistan, India, or some neighbouring countries). It is used instead of the standard 'highly skilled', and I would consider it a strong indication of the speaker's origin.
That said, I just googled the phrase, expecting a lot of Indian news sites to support my assertion, but instead found a variety of non-Asian sites, including academic work from Australia, the USA, and the UK (though of course the authors could have been from anywhere).
